# dynamically call dataframe functions based on value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have a scenario where i need to make a dynamic function call from dataframe based on the value.

```
scala> var feature="\"max\""
scala> var check=0
scala> val someDF = Seq(
     |   (8, "bat"),
     |   (64, "mouse"),
     |   (-27, "horse")
     | ).toDF("number", "word")
```

so from the above i have the max as value from check...so i need to get max of number from dataframe (someDF)

i tried with reflection by making a string like below

```
var test = s"check=someDF.agg(${feature}($col)).head().getInt(0)"
Eval[Unit](test)
```

Eval class is below

```
object Eval {

  def apply[A](string: String): A = {
    val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
    val tree = toolbox.parse(string)
    toolbox.eval(tree).asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}
```

Am getting the exception

```
scala> Eval[Unit](test)
scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:

not found: value check
```

May i request a suggestion that is there a way to make a dynamic function call from dataframe.

Thanks.

Comment: seems like scala shell has some issue - https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7081

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just call the function with the variables? You don't need to use eval at all.

```
val someDF = Seq(
    (8, "bat"),
    (64, "mouse"),
    (-27, "horse")
).toDF("number", "word")

var feature = "max"
var colname = "number"
var check=0
check = someDF.agg((colname, feature)).head().getInt(0)

// check: Int = 64
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks i missed this part. Also may i know if there is a way to call dynamically for distinct/dropDuplicate etc functions also.

Comment: @mck..sure my question also to call the functions dynamically in dataframe.. am sure this answer is helpful ... but i also need to know how to make all function calls dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? You can pass a Map[col:String,functionname:String] to agg()

```
+---+---+--------+--------+
| bf| df|duration|tel_date|
+---+---+--------+--------+
|  1|  1|       1|       1|
|  1|  1|       2|       2|
|  1|  1|       3|       3|
|  2|  2|       3|       3|
|  2|  2|       2|       2|
|  2|  2|       1|       1|
+---+---+--------+--------+

df.groupBy("bf", "df").agg(("duration","sum"),("tel_date","min"),("tel_date","max")).show()

| bf| df|sum(duration)|min(tel_date)|max(tel_date)|
+---+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  2|  2|            6|            1|            3|
|  1|  1|            6|            1|            3|
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks i missed this part. Also may i know if there is a way to call dynamically for distinct/dropDuplicate etc functions also.